# Prove that for any two real numbers a and b $\big||a|-|b|\big|< |a-b|$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I know I should use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $|a|=|(a-b)+b|\le|a-b|+|b|$. Then switch the roles of $a$ and $b$.